# How to correctly handle control-key combinations in SDL2

Tags: keyboard-events, sdl-2

In my *SDL 2.0* based application, I would like to handle both `Control +` and `Control =`.

I understand that I could handle the `SDL_KEYDOWN` event and look for the `SDLK_EQUALS` keycode in combination with `KEYMODE_CTRL`. And even check for `KEYMOD_SHIFT' to distinguish between`+`and`=`. However, this is not portable and breaks on keyboards where those symbols are mapped to different keys.

Another thing I have tried is to enable `SDL_StartTextInput()` and then listen to `SDL_TEXTINPUT` events. However that only works for printable characters. It ignores control sequences completely.

What is the correct the way to do this? I see *SDL 1.2* actually had a `unicode` field in the `SDL_Keysym` structure. That would definitely make this a lot easier for me. Does anyone know why that was removed and what the equivalent in *SDL 2.0* would be?

Comment: I think it was replaced by text input events, take a look at https://wiki.libsdl.org/Tutorials/TextInput

Comment: @keltar the problem is that the TextInput swallows the control keys.It only works for printable characters. I can read the code to see how it works internally and maybe build something similar, but I'd prefer to not do that.

Comment: But you still have keydown events for ctrl if it isn't part of input sequence, so you can combine both.

Comment: @keltar I don't get `SDL_TEXTINPUT` events for non printable control characters. Like `C-+`.

Comment: But you have one for `+` and `SDL_KEYDOWN` for ctrl, right? (at least I do)

Comment: @keltar can you show some code? I don't understand how I can recognize `+`  in `SDL_KEYDOWN`.

Comment: @StefanArentz Can you please check my questions [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217020/wkwebview-didt-give-all-cookies-in-navigationresponse) [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154918/share-wkwebview-cookies-with-uiwebview). I think you can give me answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example how you can get unicode input as SDL_TEXTINPUT but the rest as SDL_KEYDOWN:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int done = 0;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *w = SDL_CreateWindow("foo", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            640, 480, 0);

    int lctrl = 0, rctrl = 0;

    SDL_StartTextInput();
    while (!done) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                done = 1;
                break;
            case SDL_TEXTINPUT: {
                int ctrl_state = lctrl || rctrl;
                printf("%s, ctrl %s\n", event.text.text, (ctrl_state) ? "pressed" : "released");
            } break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RCTRL) { rctrl = 1; }
                else if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LCTRL) { lctrl = 1; }
                break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:
                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RCTRL) { rctrl = 0; }
                else if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LCTRL) { lctrl = 0; }
                break;
            }
        }
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(w);
    }

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

To simplify things, it ignores SDL_TEXTEDITING, which may (or not) be what you want. Also `SDL_GetKeyboardState` can be used instead of manually processing events and accumulating modifier keys flags, with the same result.

Comment: That's really great example. But maybe you'd want to add `#include <stdio.h>` to make it perfect...